# How to retrieve all the rows with date starting the first day of a month

Tags: mysql, database

How can I retrieve all the rows with a date starting the first day or the 16th of a month?

With dates like:

```
2012-03-01 11:25:00
2014-05-10 13:26:00
2013-04-16 12:24:00
2017-11-03 14:21:00
2011-10-01 09:23:00
```

I need to get all the dates starting the first day or the 16th of a month

```
2012-03-01 11:25:00
2013-04-16 12:24:00
2011-10-01 09:23:00
```

At this time, I use something like this, but I am pretty sure that it is not the most elegant way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date like '%-01 %' OR date like '%-16 %'
```

Comment: Stop.  Don't ever treat dates like strings.  Treat dates like dates and use functions to get at the desired data.  Try `where extract(day from date) in (1,16)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: `WHERE Day(date) in (1,16)` or `where dayofmonth(date) in (1,16)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day  just to name 3 possibilities.

Comment: @xQbert : cool, that's working! Convert your comment as answer to close the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yep enjoy; and Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever treat dates like strings use date functions to get at what you need...

Rule of thumb:

1. If it's a date use date functions to work with it.
2. If you'll ever need do math on it; it better be a number not a character...
3. If you'll never do math on it, and it's not a date.... store it as character.
4. The ONLY exception of which I'm aware is auto increment; which you should never do math but should be numeric (technically the engine is doing the math so i guess that fits into rule 2)

here's 3 examples to get at a day from a date.

```
WHERE extract(day from date) in (1,16)
WHERE Day(date) in (1,16) 
WHERE dayofmonth(date) in (1,16)
```

FROM DOCS:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

or

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day